# array data from json duplicated on tableview ios

Tags: ios, arrays, json, web-services, uitableview

i'm displaying data from a webservice in my tableview app but i get the array twice in the tableview.
also i'm trying to use the endless scroll to show paginated data without success

```
 (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.articlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self fetchData:1];

}
```

my function to fetch data

```
-(void) fetchData:(int)page {
NSString *urlString = [NSString
                       stringWithFormat:@"http://url?page=%d", (int)page];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSData *theData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:nil
                                                    error:nil];

self.articlesArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:nil];

[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ArticleCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ArticleCell"];
}
```

and here's my tableview methods please see what i did wrong

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (section==0)
 {
 return [self.articlesArray count];
else
 return [self.articlesArray count];
}
//  return [self.articlesArray count]; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
 if (3 == (row % 4)) {  // or 0 == if you  want the first cell to be an ad!
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"AdCell";
AdViewCell  *cell = (AdViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass: AdViewCell.class]))
{
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AdCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
cell = [[AdViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
 }
   GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle];

 bannerView.adUnitID =@"";
 bannerView.rootViewController =self;
 GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
 [bannerView loadRequest:request];

 [cell.contentView addSubview:bannerView];

 return cell;
}
 else{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
ArticleViewCell *cell = (ArticleViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier ];
if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass: ArticleViewCell.class]))
{
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ArticleCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1];
cell = [[ArticleViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] ;
}
NSDictionary * tempDictionary = [self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSString *imageUrl = [[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"featured_image"];
 imageUrl = [imageUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 [cell.thumbnailImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl ] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageRetryFailed completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
if (image){
    // Set your image over here
}else{
    //something went wrong
    NSLog(@"Error occured : %@", [error description]);
}

}];
NSString * title=[tempDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"title.rendered"];

cell.titleLabel.text = title;

return cell;
}


}
```

Comment: Please post more code (numberOfItemsInSection, numberOfSections, cellForItemAt)

Comment: You're not showing enough code to figure out what's wrong. One suggestion is to set a breakpoint on numberOfRowsInSection and to compare this to the amount of rows you are expecting. Also registerNib should be in viewDidLoad as it only needs to be set up once. With the code above you're registering the nib every time you fetchData and you should only be doing that once.

Comment: BTW, you can also hard code the data in articlesArray and bypass calling fetchData to to help isolate the issue.

Comment: please see update

Comment: Cross verify the JSON whether data is repeating?

Comment: i log it and no it is not. i think it has something to do with the reloaddata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove duplicate values once you get response from json, before reload tableview remove duplicate elements from array

```
NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:YourArray];

NSArray *arrayWithoutDuplicates = [orderedSet array];
```

Thanks

Comment: the array has 10 objects with no duplicates i double checked its the tableview that displays it twice

Comment: please check inside numberOfRowsInSection , that must be a issue as you are passing two times same array

Comment: the numberOfRowsInSection is exact as my webservice returns 10 objects by page

Comment: if you want to display only one cell in section 0 then remains into other section then try below code into numberOfRowsInSection
if (section==0)
 {
 return 1;
}else{
 return [self.articlesArray count];
}